# On average, how fast do iOS users upgrade to the latest version?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Until recently, I have been happily ignoring iOS5 SDK because its new features aren't really essential to the products I'm working on. Also, third-party tools (e.g. Corona SDK) don't support it until it's officially out, because part of the NDA you have to agree to before you can download the SDK beta says "you can't talk about it publicly".

But now that it's officially out, and officially supported by third-party tools, I feel that I have to start working on it. Not yet urgently, but soon.

If the feature set of the latest iOS version is not a consideration, and my only objective is to "target the platform where the most iOS users are", when should I target iOS 5? Up to when should I support iOS 4? iOS 3?

Comment: This is not an answerable question. On average, how do you speak for everyone that is an iOS user except yourself? Voting to close as "not constructive", as this has no definitive answer. Which would you accept as the correct answer - "every two months", "every 10 days", "once a year", "immediately when it's announced", "every once in a while", or "when they need a new feature"?

Comment: I remember in the heydays of Flash, they were boasting that the latest version is at 95% adoption six months after its release, compared to the latest version of IE which is at 25% one year after its release. Is there a similar rule of thumb for iOS adoption?

Comment: I don't understand why this is not constructive. Maybe the title isn't accurate but I explained in the question text - the reason I asked this is because I like to know when should I start targeting the next iOS version. As I explained in my comment above, Flash used to release adoption rates. Maybe Apple won't release their numbers but I'm pretty sure some analytics company has done some number crunching and they've released their figures which is pretty close (and useful!) even if it is not the exact number.

Comment: Ah, Google answered it for me better than SO did: http://www.accella.net/when-to-start-developing-for-ios5/. iOS5 adoption is roughly following the same curve for iOS4: 50% after the first month, 70% after 3 months and 90% 6 months. So if you have a 6-month development cycle, start as soon as the new iOS is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS 5 is free and it has killer features, it is being adopted fast.

> Localytics analyzes usage of software by embedding their code in the desired application. After collecting the usage and download data, and by putting the resulting data into different metrics they get the relevant information and provide it to their client. This way an application manufacturer can have a full report on the usage of its application, in various type of users, usage patterns, usage durations and so on.
>
> ...
>
> As we know iPhone 4S comes built in with iOS 5. So this can produce dissonance in the results. Surprisingly, not so much, **when they removed iPhone 4S from the chart, the percentage of active iOS 5 users dropped to 31%.** This result shows a very fast adoption rate.

http://www.encyclocell.com/top-news/ios-5-used-by-1-in-3-apple-devices

Comment: So what's the "average adoption rate" for all users? That's the question at hand. Do you have a definitive, accurate answer that could be accepted as being the "right" answer?

Comment: I updated the post with the relevant information. Only apple has definitive information and they have not released that data yet.

Comment: +1 since it's a good answer to a difficult question

Answer (score 2):

Even if you do not target iOS5 specifically, you should move to ARC as soon as possible.  iOS4  adoption is nearly universal and ARC will work with binaries targeting iOS4 (I think 4.1).

The other thing to consider is that iOS5 is the OS that will pretty much eliminate your question since going forward easy over the air installs will mean IOS users will be far more likely to be up to date.

To answer your actual question, we don't yet know what iOS5 adoption looks like, but in the past adoption happened pretty rapidly (by mobile platform standards).

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it, but it really depends.  I upgraded to iOS5 the day it came out, but I have a friend who only just upgraded his iPhone 3G to iOS4.x

Unless you are using the specific features that iOS5 provides, an application targeted at 4.x should be fine for quite some time.

I wouldn't publish an app for iOS5 alone for several months, unless I had to use the new features.

Comment: @KenWhite - Like you I have voted to close the question, but I think a downvote on the answer would be a little rough (not that I am biased of course).  You are right, there is no set numeric answer to this question.  Its a bit like the "which browser, or which screen resolution do I target" - to which the answer is usually to try to target the app at the widest audience, unless you are using specific features of the newer/better os/browser/screen-size. It is a judgement that can only be answered by you and your knowledge of the application you are making and your customer base.

Comment: In all honesty that was what I was trying to get across - and I thought a comment would be too small - have too poor formatting.

Comment: This would be a good comment -I'm not sure it's an answer. (To be honest, the mouse hovered over the downvote button for a second or two, and then the flag button, tempted to flag as "not an answer", but I managed to rein it in and just click to post this comment. There's no answer here, unless you can specify a specific average time as the question asked. Also, see my comment about which **guess** would be accepted as right. I'm only not downvoting this answer because you specifically said "it really depends". I do feel that that qualification makes this a comment and not an answer, however.

Comment: I didn't downvote either; just voted to close as "not constructive".

Comment: @KenWhite - I know, I was just responding to your comment, which was  fair comment, so deserved an answer.