# Deployment rate of new IOS versions

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there any knowledge about the new-IOS-version deployment rate after a new version of IOS is deployed and how it progress over time until the new version is +80% or more of the possible population?

What i am interested in how many users, in average given there is statistics, i will miss if i submit an app using the latest version of IOS as target vs. using a few generation older IOS release.

Comment: possible duplicate of [On average, how fast do iOS users upgrade to the latest version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924551/on-average-how-fast-do-ios-users-upgrade-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: [Here](http://www.marco.org/2011/08/13/instapaper-ios-device-and-version-stats-update) is some data but it has a few caveats (listed in the article)